# Javascript. Creating Array-like objects. Is it possible to make .length autoincrement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

There is so much about creating and inheritance of Array-like objects, but one of my questions remains unanswered: is it possible somehow to add a auto-incrementing `.length` property to the object?
Sample script:

```
function ArrayLike(){
    this.length=0;
    this.splice=[].splice;
}
var Arr=new ArrayLike();
Arr[0]=0;
Arr[1]=1;
alert(Arr.length); //alerts "0" instead of "2"
```

Of course, i can add some method like:

```
function ArrayLike(){
    this.length=0;
    this.splice=[].splice;
    this.push=function(toadd){
        this[this.length++]=toadd;
    }
}
```

But this is not what I'm trying to do.

So is it possible to increment .length when I add something to the object in a way `Arr[N]='blah-blah-blah'`?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Just use an `Array()`, and add extra properties to it, if you with. In JavaScript, `Array`s are also objects. They _can_ have properties: `var Arr = [0, 1]; arr.myProperty = "foobar";` I'm not saying any of this is a good idea, though.

Comment: Your best option is probably making length a method, not a property.

Comment: Please don't downvote this question.  It is not written badly and does not fail in any other metric.  If he fails to see why this is not a good idea, then the answer should explain why, that's all.

Comment: @Cerbrus The main aim is to clone Array object without unnecessary (in my case) methods (join, concat, forEach, etc.), but extended with methods I need. To win a small bit of performance while iterating, or just not to have it overloaded with extra methods. Not that I really in a need of using `Arr[N]='value'` method, but it would be really nice to have.

Comment: @MadBrozzeR: You really won't gain _any_ performance by copying part of the `Array` functionality. It's a native object that's well-optimized in modern browsers. Writing your own implementation will negate that optimization, not to mention the loops you'd have to jump through to actually make it work.

Comment: @MadBrozzeR: *"To win a small bit of performance while iterating..."* I can't see any gain by using your own object over a native array, can you explain where you think you'll get that gain? *"...or just not to have it overloaded with extra methods."* The "extra" methods don't "load" individual array instances in any way at all. Individual array instances have only their own properties, the "extra" methods are on the *prototype* that sits behind them. There is zero cost associated with them on a per-object basis.

Comment: I guess you are right. So, let's say, this was an educational case.

Comment: Then will it be better performance solution to inherit Array object and to extend it with desired methods?

Comment: @MadBrozzeR: Sadly, even with ES5 you can't quite inherit from `Array`, some of its magic is too magic. Simplest thing is to "mix in" your methods on specific array instances. Or if you like, you can add your methods to `Array.prototype`. In both cases, just be careful to make the new properties for those non-enumerable, or make sure none of your code is using `for-in` for looping arrays without safeguards (more about that [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476)).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "_Simplest thing is to "mix in" your methods on specific array instances._" - Just the way I'm doing it right now... searched for better solution.
`"Array.prototype"` - I try to avoid native prototypes overloading.

Comment: @MadBrozzeR: No, the opposite of what you're doing. I'll demonstrate in my answer in a mo'....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible somehow to add autoincrement .length property

Not really; at least, you can't do all the things `Array` does around `length` and index properties.

In an ES5-enabled environment, you can make `length` a property with getter and setter functions. But it's awkward to find out what `length` should be, because there's (so far) no "catch all" way of setting it when code like:

```
arr[1] = "foo";
```

...runs. (ES6 may well make it possible to have catch-all property setters, via proxies.)

So your `length` would have to figure it out from the object contents, which is not going to be very efficient, e.g.:

```
var explicitLength;
Object.defineProperty(this, "length", {
    get: function() {
        var length;

        // Find our length from our max index property
        length = Object.keys(this).reduce(function(maxIndex, key) {
            var index = key === "" ? NaN : +key;
            if (!isNaN(index) && index > maxIndex) {
                return index;
            }
            return maxIndex;
        }, -1) + 1;

        // If we have an explicitly-set length, and it's greater,
        // use that instead. Note that if explicitLength is
        // `undefined`, the condition will always be false.
        if (explicitLength > length) {
            length = explicitLength;
        }

        return length;
    },
    set: function(value) {
        explicitLength = value;
        // You might choose to have code here removing properties
        // defining indexes >= value, likes Array does
    }
});
```

Note that even when we have an explicitly-set length, we still have to check to see if the natural length is greater, to deal with:

```
arr.length = 2;
arr[5] = "foo";
console.log(arr.length); // Should be 6, not 2
```

Doing that much work on a property retrieval is obviously not a good thing, so I would steer clear of this sort of thing.

---

Above I said *"...so I would steer clear of this sort of thing."*

Well that's all very well and good, but what should you do instead?

Suppose you have the functions `nifty` and `spiffy` that you want to have available. You have two realistic options:

1. Use an actual array, and mix in your custom methods to each array instance
2. Enhance `Array.prototype`

#### #1 Use an actual array and mix in your methods

You'd define your methods on a convenient object, say `ArrayMixin`:

```
var ArrayMixin = {
    nifty: function() {
        // ...do something nifty with `this`
    },
    spiffy: function() {
        // ...do something spiffy with `this`
    }
};
```

Then have a builder function for creating arrays:

```
function createArray(arr) {
    arr = arr || []; // `arr` is optional
    extend(arr, ArrayMixin);
    return arr;
}
```

What's this `extend` function, you ask? Something that copies properties from one object to another. If you use any libraries or frameworks (jQuery, Underscore, Angular, PrototypeJS, ...), they're likely to have an `extend` function of some kind that does this. The usually look *something* like this (this is very off-the-cuff).

```
function extend(target) {
    var arg, obj, key;
    for (arg = 1; arg < arguments.length; ++arg) {
        obj = arguments[arg];
        for (key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                target[key] = obj[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

Note that that's a shallow copy, and it doesn't bother to try to make the properties it adds to `target` non-enumerable. Tweak as desired.

So then when you want an array:

```
var a = createArray(['one', 'two', 'three']);
```

...and `a` has `nifty` and `spiffy` on it.

Example:

```js
var ArrayMixin = {
  nifty: function() {
    this.forEach(function(entry, index) {
      this[index] = entry.toUpperCase();
    }, this);
    return this;
  },
  spiffy: function() {
    this.forEach(function(entry, index) {
      this[index] = entry.toLowerCase();
    }, this);
    return this;
  }
};

function createArray(arr) {
  arr = arr || []; // `arr` is optional
  extend(arr, ArrayMixin);
  return arr;
}

function extend(target) {
  var arg, obj, key;
  for (arg = 1; arg < arguments.length; ++arg) {
    obj = arguments[arg];
    for (key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        target[key] = obj[key];
      }
    }
  }
  return target;
}

var a = createArray(['one', 'two', 'three']);
a.nifty();
snippet.log(a.join(", "));
a.spiffy();
snippet.log(a.join(", "));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

#### Enhance `Array.prototype`

People freak out about enhancing `Array.prototype`, but there's really nothing wrong with it. The only reason it causes trouble is if people use broken code that expects `for-in` to loop through array indexes *and* you've had to enhance the prototype without making the new methods non-enumerable. But again, that code is broken; `for-in` **isn't** for looping through array indexes, it's for looping through object properties.

So here's enhancing `Array.prototype`:

```
(function(aproto) {
    var add;
    if (Object.defineProperty) {
        // Function to add a non-enumerable property
        add = function(obj, prop, value) {
            Object.definePrperty(obj, prop, {
                value: value
            });
        };
    } else {
        // Old JavaScript engine, oh well
        add = function(obj, prop, value) {
            obj[prop] = value;
        };
    }

    add(aproto, "nifty", function() {
        // ...do something nifty with `this`
    });

    add(aproto, "spiffy", function() {
        // ...do something spiffy with `this`
    });

})(Array.prototype);
```

Now, using it is really clean:

```
var a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

...and `a` has `nifty` and `spiffy` on it.

Example:

```js
(function(aproto) {
  var add;
  if (Object.defineProperty) {
    // Function to add a non-enumerable property
    add = function(obj, prop, value) {
      Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
        value: value
      });
    };
  } else {
    // Old JavaScript engine, oh well
    add = function(obj, prop, value) {
      obj[prop] = value;
    };
  }

  add(aproto, "nifty", function() {
    this.forEach(function(entry, index) {
      this[index] = entry.toUpperCase();
    }, this);
  });

  add(aproto, "spiffy", function() {
    this.forEach(function(entry, index) {
      this[index] = entry.toLowerCase();
    }, this);
  });

})(Array.prototype);


var a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
a.nifty();
snippet.log(a.join(", "));
a.spiffy();
snippet.log(a.join(", "));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: ^ This is why it's basically a good idea to work with a `Array()` as your "source". Extend that (if you _have_ to), instead of trying to copy functions.

Comment: Well, this is totally not a way to simplicity, but anyway, the answer satisfies the question.

Comment: @MadBrozzeR: Re simplicity: Exactly. :-) Much better off just using an array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Like I said before, the way I do it right now (in my js library, not here) is very similar to _"Use an actual array, and mix in your custom methods to each array instance"_, but without an extra object:

    `var arr=NLtoARR(NodeList);`
    `arr.Nprops=1;`
    `arr.Nmeths=function(){return};`
    `return arr;`

I came here to ask for better solution. So, I guess, I prefer this one now.
Thank you. The answer is accepted.

Comment: Just checked for performance between `new Array()` and `new ArrayLike()` (custom object). The first one is much faster.

Comment: @MadBrozzeR: Right. And you basically never need to use `new Array()`. Use `[]` instead. Faster still.